# Ruby: how to match a double quote in a regexp

Tags: ruby, regex, escaping, gsub

I am trying to remove some double quotes (") characters from a text file using a Ruby one liner, with little success.

I have tried the following, and some variations, without success.

```
ruby -pe 'gsub(/\"/,"")' < myfile.txt
```

This gives me the following error:

```
-e:1: Invalid argument - < (Errno::EINVAL)
```

I am running Ruby on a Win machine:

**ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [i386-mswin32]**

Any idea?

Comment: Need more data: are you using the cmd shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like cmd quoting hell -- note that single quotes are meaningless in the cmd shell.

```
ruby -pe "gsub(34.chr,'')" < filename
```

but this is probably better:

```
ruby -pe "$_.delete!(34.chr)" < filename
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
ruby -e 'puts $stdin.read.gsub(34.chr,"")' <myfile.txt
```

Comment: There's something with backslashes and cmd.exe that doesn't play well.

Answer (score 0):

```
ruby -pe 'gsub(/\"/,"")' myfile.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. I need the "<" to redirect the input to the script.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't get "redirect the input to the script"

Comment: What I mean is that the input is coming from a file and that the "<" sign is used to feed the script with that file. Maybe these examples can explain it better: http://www.fepus.net/ruby1line.txt

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem is with the shell.

Your error message is from Ruby, so it seems Ruby is receiving the `<` as an argument. This means the shell isn't doing any redirection.

I don't have a Windows machine handy so I'd double check that you're getting the redirection right first. On first inspection I think the `< myfile.txt` should be `<myfile.txt`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the cause. With non special characters it works fine.